# is there a use case for `apt-get install` without `update`?

Tags: apt

Every time I see instructions to run `apt-get install`, it says to run `apt-get update`first. Same for `upgrade` and `dist-upgrade`.

Why doesn't install automatically do `update`? Is there a case where you don't want that?

Answer (score 3):

`apt-get update` updates the lists of available packages and their version numbers.

The use case you are searching for could be: If you want to run `apt-get install` twice in a short time, you only need to run `apt-get update` once because the package lists are unlikely to have been changed in the meantime.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the other answer, `apt-get update` updates the list of available packages. So, unless the list of available packages has changed, it's simply wasting time and (not much) bandwith.

The reason why you often see `apt-get update` before `apt-get install` is twofold:

- Often this is in the context of *adding a PPA* or some other package source; in this case, you obviously need to update the list of available packages because the first thing you've done is to add to the list of available packages.
- During the development period the archives are changing quite rapidly; there can be hundreds of changes to the package lists over the course of a day, so it will often make sense to `apt-get update` first so you don't try to download a version that's no longer available. Once the distro is released the number of changes drops dramatically - generally down to no more than a couple each week. There's little point in running `apt-get update` before an install in this case.

Comment: As mentioned in Erik Sjölund's [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/117167/22949), `apt-get update` doesn't just update the list of _what_ packages are available _from where_, but also _what versions are available_. This changes whenever an update is released, and in practical use, getting information about new _versions_ of old packages is the _primary_ benefit of `apt-get update`. Even when a release is stable, [important updates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) are released for it, including updates for critical security vulnerabilities. This is hardly a waste of time.

Comment: It's not a waste of time to run _periodically_ - and, indeed, by default it *is* run automatically every day. It would be a waste of time to run before every `apt-get` invocation, which was what the question was asking.

Comment: Many computers used as workstations are not connected to the Internet for all or even most of the time they are running, or are configured not to check for updates automatically. Many server systems are configured not to do so either (and there, software is rarely installed using graphical tools that automatically `update` first). These are the reasons most authors recommend running `apt-get update` before `apt-get install`/`apt-get upgrade` *in general* (though indeed not when you have *just* run `apt-get update`).

Comment: Here's what I don't get: why am I supposed to update the **entire** list when I've only just installed maybe 1-2 PPA's? Is it because of package dependencies and such, that may come from other sources? I don't like that I query a bunch of different places needlessly every time I want to install something (and on that note, I feel like having an auto-update-when-installing-from-source feature would be intuitive).

Answer (score 1):

Besides [having run `sudo apt-get update` very recently](https://askubuntu.com/a/117167/22949), there are a few other situations where you might decide not to run it before running `sudo apt-get install ...`:

- You are installing software from a *local* software source that is already configured, such as a CD/DVD or USB flash drive with an Ubuntu ISO burned/written to it.
- You know you have the package you wish to install cached locally (in `/var/cache/apt/archives`), either from it being installed before, or having run `sudo apt-get --download-only install ...`, and you want to install it from there rather than downloading it.

  (Perhaps you want to do something with that version even if it isn't the latest, or your Internet connection is very slow, or you are not connected to the Internet.)
- You know there is no later version of the package available. For example, the [Launchpad page for `nano` in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nano) shows that only the "release" versions are available--nothing is available in "security" or "updates" or "proposed." (In contrast, you can see that [`firefox` in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox) does have such updates.)
- You want to save time, even at the risk of possibly installing an older package than the recommended version, or even of the installation failing because the package your system wants to install is no longer available, or is listed as having dependencies that are no longer available, or that conflict with some newer software already on your system.

  If your system is configured to check for updates automatically and is connected to the Internet 24/7, this risk might be considered low enough to forego manually running `sudo apt-get update` most of the time (see [RAOF's answer and the comments there](https://askubuntu.com/a/117201/22949)).